# Need help using nested or multiple ARRAYFORMULA's in google sheet dashboard

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have a dashboard that I enter link description here am trying to lookup clients based off of billings per month. the formula required two criteria looking up the Client and the Type of account they have. Some clients have multiple accounts so hence the reason the two criteria lookup is necessary. I can get the formula to work without referencing the month with this line:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(iferror(vlookup($A8&$B8, {'Run Rate'!$B$2:$B&'Run Rate'!$C$2:$C,'Run Rate'!$D$2:$I}, 6, 0),""))
```

But when I try to add referencing the month tab it will not work:

```
=IF($A$2 = "January 2019",ARRAYFORMULA(iferror(vlookup($A6&$B6, {'Run Rate01'!$B$2:$B&'Run Rate01'!$C$2:$C,'Run Rate01'!$D$2:$I}, 6, 0),
IF($A$2 = "February 2019",ARRAYFORMULA(iferror(vlookup($A6&$B6, {'Run Rate02'!$B$2:$B&'Run Rate02'!$C$2:$C,'Run Rate02'!$D$2:$I}, 6, 0),
IF($A$2 = "March 2019",ARRAYFORMULA(iferror(vlookup($A6&$B6, {'Run Rate03'!$B$2:$B&'Run Rate03'!$C$2:$C,'Run Rate03'!$D$2:$I}, 6, 0),"")))))))))
```

[Here is the sample Dashboard](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/123xrQHj3tJAQW53n0QPkG1_JsfGGxaGWYA201SKV8CU/edit?usp=sharing)

If you have another way of doing this I would love some advice as well.  Any assistance will help.

Comment: pls, explain why is relevant to have reference of A2? it doesn't affect anything and its pointless. it doesn't make any sense. what exactly are you after?

Comment: also, you want that to be trimmed down by start date column or end date column?

Comment: ARRAYFORMULA is not a loop. In general, nested ARRAYFORMULAS don't work. The outermost one will provide the array context and the inner ones will have no effect. To have a 2-criteria VLOOKUP, the most common solution is to make a column combining the 2 criteria into a single value.

Comment: @player0 I created this to obfuscate my company's client list. it is really just a sample of all the data. The start date and end date just tell us how many billable hours each client has based of their contract. Each month new clients are added and other drop off even though they don't in my sample sheet. The Run Rate tab is updated monthly. The billed tabs are updated daily. We are trying to capture all of a clients billable hours for each client. By changing the month we can see how each account manager is doing on their billings.

Answer (score 0):

paste in C6, drag over D6 and then drag down:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A6&$B6, 
 QUERY({'Run Rate02'!$B$2:$B&'Run Rate02'!$C$2:$C, 'Run Rate02'!$D$2:$I},
 "where Col4>=date'"&
 TEXT(DATE(RIGHT($A$2, 4), MONTH(SPLIT($A$2, " ")&1),   1), "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
    and Col4< date'"&
 TEXT(DATE(RIGHT($A$2, 4), MONTH(SPLIT($A$2, " ")&1)+1, 1), "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"),
 COLUMN()+3, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This query actually helped me with another question on the same dashboard. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

I got the results I needed with this formula:

=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(IF($A$2 = "January 2019",vlookup($A6&$B6, {'Run Rate01'!$B$2:$B&'Run Rate01'!$C$2:$C,'Run Rate01'!$D$2:$I}, 6, 0), IF($A$2 = "February 2019",vlookup($A6&$B6, {'Run Rate02'!$B$2:$B&'Run Rate02'!$C$2:$C,'Run Rate02'!$D$2:$I}, 6, 0), IF($A$2 = "March 2019",vlookup($A6&$B6, {'Run Rate03'!$B$2:$B&'Run Rate03'!$C$2:$C,'Run Rate03'!$D$2:$I}, 6, 0),"")))))